# How to know when a client has disconnected in Socket.IO because of network issues?

Tags: javascript, sockets

I have a situation to handle where the client connects to the socket and lost the network connection.

In the above situation how can the server know.

Comment: You haven't specified what backend your server is running - the Javascript tag you used specifies the code running on the client end (in the browser), but what are you using on the server? Please edit your post and tag the backend code (node.js if that's what you're using).

Comment: socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   // Handle here
}); is my serve code

Answer (score 0):

The `disconnect` event also fires when the client gets disconnected because of loosing *network connection*. So the following will still get executed in your case

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   // Handle here
});
```

Comment: Actually i am using mobile for client.I turned off the WiFi.But the disconnect method doesn't called in ap.js.

Comment: @AjayReddy. It should fire, wait for sometime after switching off WiFi.

Comment: its firing time out after some time not the disconnect